# Can't open photo using PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I try to open photo using PIL ,but it won't open.

How can I get it done?

This is my code and error message:

```py
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('test.png')
```

```
File "imagetest.py", line 3, in <module>
    img = Image.open('test.png')
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2687, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file 'test.png'
```

Comment: Try giving the full path of the image.

Comment: Passing only the file name (without the full path) as the parameter, will only work if the image is in the same directory as your script file. Try passing the full path as @AchinthaIhalage mentioned

Comment: I don't think the file not being in the same directory is the problem, it sounds like the image might be corrupt, can you upload the image to verify it?